# How to add an element using a custom SOAPHandler

Tags: java, xml, soaphandler

This is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197355/how-to-properly-format-a-soap-message-envelope-using-a-custom-soaphandler).  I've pulled out the main problem as I've updated much of the code but I still have an issue.  How can I have a custom SOAPHandler class add a new element to a SOAP message?  I need to add a username and password to the message.  If I use:

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

  SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage();
  SOAPPart part = msg.getSOAPPart();
  SOAPEnvelope envelope = part.getEnvelope();

  .... //additional header information

  SOAPElement element.addChildElement("Username", "sse");
  element.addTextNode("user1");
  element.addChildElement("Password", "sse");
  element.addTextNode("1234");
}
```

I end up with this where the tags are closed and the values aren't enclosed:

```
<sse:Username/>user1
<sse:Password/>1234
```

I want to end up with the username and password formatted like this:

```
<sse:Username>user1</sse:Username>
<sse:Password>1234</sse:Password>
```

How can I get the values (user1 and 1234) enclosed in the element?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
element.addChildElement("Password", "sse").addTextNode("1234");
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that the line

```
SOAPElement element.addChildElement("Username", "sse");
```

isn't valid java, you need to remember that `addChildElement` returns the newly-created child element, and you need to add the text nodes to that, not to the parent. All your code is doing is adding a child node (empty), then adding a text node, then another empty child, then another text node.

You probably want this:

```
element.addChildElement("Username", "sse").addTextNode("user1");
element.addChildElement("Password", "sse").addTextNode("1234");
```

As a final note, talking to an SEE web service from java will only lead to tears and loss of hair. Microsoft SEE web services are not standards compliant (shocking, I know).